# Which method to decrease a variable based on MySQL table data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello StackOverflow community,

first I want to explain that I posted this problem yesterday, but recognized that people don't really understand what the problem is. So I deleted my question and questions and answers for a clearer explanation. If this is not allowed, I am sorry and never do this again.

I have a table called 'orders', let say for candies. Candy merchants can bid and ask for candies for different prices and package sizes.

It can happen that I have two candy-packages (package 1 has 10 candies and package 2 has 11 candies) for the total amount of 21 candies merchants are offering. Now there is another party (called C) who wants to buy 25 candies. Of course this are 4 candies to much so we want to clear as good as possible and calculate 25 candies - 21 candies and the C has a rest of 4 candies I add to my table until the next supplement.
This means that I delete package 1 and package 2 after I calculated (25 - 10 - 11) and insert the new value which is 4 (you remember, 25 - 10 - 11).

For this I want to create an algorithm/script. This says, in very simplified pseudocode:

```
WHILE-loop initiation
IF ($candy_demand_new_offer > $candy_supply_most_recent_row)
{
$candy_demand_new_offer = $candy_demand_new_offer - $candy_supply_most_recent_row;
DELETE $candy_supply_most_recent_row;
INSERT $candy_demand_new_offer;
}
```

After this would follow some else ifs for the case that demand is lower than supply.
But what I get are two new entries. This entries are 15 and 4 because the script first calculates (25 - 10 = 15) and (15 - 11 = 4). Of course my INSERT is the problem, but I can't leave it blank. Because when there is no other recent supply I must insert the rest of the candy demand into the table. But not showing every single step, but the final result.

Now how can I do this? Maybe I got mad or the problem is more complicated than I thought.

Thanks for any help and hope you understand my problem description. If not, please tell me and I learn to get better.

Comment: You need to take a step back and think about your data model.  It sounds like you are trying to track all this data in a single table, which is probably not the model you are looking for.  I would imagine that, at a minimum, you would need tables for: items available for order, orders, a mapping for how you may be able to map order request to supply, and a table representing completed transactions (orders that are fulfilled). There is probably even more complexity than that depending on your business logic for how you want to mark supply to be fulfilled against orders.

Comment: Hi @MikeBrant, thank you for your answer. For simplification I hid some details of my code. One was an INSERT into a table called successful orders as you mentioned. And the whole code works, but it only does by 100% if demand is smaller than supply. The problem I have is if supply is smaller than demand because there get every calculation step (using the example above there are two calculation steps) inserted in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psuedo-code answer:

```
while ($candies_needed > 0 && $row = fetch) {
    if ($candies_needed >= $row['candies_available']) {
        $candies_needed -= $row['candies_available'];
        DELETE this row from inventory table;
    } else {
        UPDATE this row in inventory table SET candies_available = candies_available - $candies_needed;
        $candies_needed = 0;
    }
}
if ($candies_needed > 0) { // Haven't fullfilled the entire order
    INSERT $candies_needed into order table;
}
```